# Pine Script Panels

Tags: panel, pine-script

I have a strategy based on my indicator. When adding the strategy i'd like to plot both the indicator and the equity but in different panels. Is there a property in plot that allows me to do that.
NB. I don't want to overlay either on the price chart.

Comment: You just have to remove the `overlay=true` parameter from your `strategy()` function, or set it to `overlay=false`. Then it'll show in a separate panel.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do is plot different parts of the same indicator/strategy in separate panels.

Comment: That cannot be done in Pine. You'll have to use separate scripts for that.